# Orthogonal transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$\langle(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\rangle= 2x_1x_2-2x_1y_2-2x_2y_1+5y_1y_2$.

Find an orthogonal linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

There is a process to find such transformation?

Comment: The identity is always orthogonal.

Comment: $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is *orthogonal* if $\langle T(x_1,y_1),T(x_2,y_2) \rangle = \langle (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \rangle$?

Comment: @azif00 yes of course

Comment: Then what about the @mechanodroid's answer?

Comment: @mechanodroid Sure, but $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ isn't an orthogonal matrix in respect to the given inner product.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ and $z = (x, y)$. Solve for $a, b, c, d$ such that $<Az, z>$ = 0.

With some algebra, you can see that $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \frac{5}{2} \alpha \\ \alpha & -\alpha \end{bmatrix}$ for any non-zero $\alpha$ works.